# VB.net delegate param array with invoke

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in my Parser and I want to pass text to Form1 so I can update some Labels or whatever.
(My structure is as follows: Form1 -> Engine -> Parser)
Sometimes I need to pass 2 strings, sometimes more.

```
Public Class Parser
Public Event NewInfo(<[ParamArray]()> Byval strArray() as String)

Public Sub SomeParser(ByVal m As Match)
Dim strArray() As String = {"Word1", "Word2"}
RaiseEvent NewInfo(strArray)
End Sub

End Class
```

Then I have this another class. I pass the Array to Engine and after that, to Form1, finally:

```
Public Class Engine
Private parent as Form1
Private WithEvents Parser As New Parser

Private Sub New(ByRef parent as Form1)
Me.parent = parent
EndSub

Private Sub ChangeLabel(ByVal str() As String) Handles Parser.NewInfo
parent.UpdateTextLabel(str)
End Sub
```

And then I have this in Form1:

```
Public Class Form1
Private WithEvents Engine as New Engine(Me)
Public Delegate Sub UpdateTextLabelDelegate(<[ParamArray]()> ByVal text() As String)
Public Sub UpdateTextLabel(ByVal ParamArray str() As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
      Me.Invoke(New UpdateTextLabelDelegate(AddressOf UpdateTextLabel), str())
    Else
(Do stuff here)
End Sub
End Class
```

The code stops at Me.invoke(New UpdateTextLabelDelegate).... -line.
Exception is something like: System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException
So it means something like wrong amount of parameters.. How to do this properly?

I would be very pleased if someone could explain and if I could understand how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to solve this problem. It wasn't that difficult but my mistake was something inside my own head.

I made no changes to Parser.vb so the above code is Ok.
Also, no changes to Engine.vb.
Changes to Form1.vb are here:

```
Public Class Form1
Private WithEvents Engine as New Engine(Me)
Public Delegate Sub UpdateTextLabelDelegate(<[ParamArray]()> ByVal text() As String)
Public Sub UpdateTextLabel(ByVal str() As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
      Me.Invoke(New UpdateTextLabelDelegate(AddressOf UpdateTextLabel), New Object() {str})
    Else
'(Do stuff here)
End Sub
End Class
```

So, all I did was to insert `New Object() {args}` to the invoke line and removed `ParamArray` from the `Public Sub UpdateTextLabel` -line..
But thanks for Kicking my head so I had the reason to go forward! :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need `<[ParamArray]()>` in your code since it's already an array that you are passing:

```
Public Delegate Sub UpdateTextLabelDelegate(ByVal text() As String)
```

And as far as passing the data through the invoke, don't use `str()`, just `str`

```
Public Sub UpdateTextLabel(ByVal str() As String)
  If Me.InvokeRequired Then
    Me.Invoke(New UpdateTextLabelDelegate(AddressOf UpdateTextLabel), str)
  Else
    '(Do stuff here)
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't really solve anything. Exactly the same problem persists. I also followed this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640145/delegates-and-paramarray-workaround-suggestions
"Delegates and ParamArray - Workaround Suggestions?"

Comment: Also I need to mention.. I am coming from another thread. I have a thread called "Engine" that is why I need this delegate in the first place.