# Call a Sub With Parameters from Another Sub

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Good day Gurus!
Am trying to call a Sub that has parameter from another Sub using Action but not working.
Please I have tried to solve this error but couldn't.

I have two **Sub** in my BasePage in ASP.Net as shown below;

```
Sub Check(mySub As Action)
    mySub()
End Sub
Sub TestMsg(g As String)
    MsgBox(g)
End Sub
```

And on click event LinkButton, am trying to call **TestMsg** through **Check** as below

```
Private Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click
    Check(AddressOf TestMsg("Call a sub from another"))
End Sub
```

But am getting an error message that says **addressof operand must be the name of a method (without parenthesis)**

Please what is the solution to this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using WebForms in 2022?

Comment: `TestMsg` is not an `Action`. An `Action` delegate has no parameters. `TestMsg` is actually an `Action<String>` (well... `Action(Of String)`). You should use a VB lambda-expression to invoke `TestMsg` with a string argument: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions

Comment: It is a local website that has been under used only trying to improved on some of the codes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around it with a trick, but it feels like it defeats the purpose

```vb
Private Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click
    Check(Sub() TestMsg("Call a sub from another"))
End Sub
```

To make it work the way you want, you might make a generic overload and call that

```vb
Sub Check(mySub As Action)
    mySub()
End Sub
Sub Check(Of T)(mySub As Action(Of T), arg As T)
    mySub(arg)
End Sub
Sub TestMsg(g As String)
    MsgBox(g)
End Sub

Private Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click
    Check(AddressOf TestMsg, "Call a sub from another")
End Sub
```

Still, it would be easier to just call

```vb
TestMsg("Call a sub from another")
```

You can use a different version of `Action` depending on the signatures of your method.

```vb
Sub Check(Of T)(mySub As Action(Of T, String, String), arg1 As T, arg2 As String, arg3 As String)
```

Or you can loosely use a single `Action(Of Object())` to pass a varying number of arguments to a method, but you lose tight coupling. You'll need to trust that the caller has information about the requirements of `args`, such as in my example below, it requires an object, integer, double (or something which is castable to those). Inspired by this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2640145/832052)

```vb
Public Sub TestMsg(ParamArray args As Object())
    If args.Length > 0 Then
        Console.Write(args(0))
        If args.Length > 1 Then
            Dim i = CInt(args(1))
            Console.Write($", {i + 5}")
            If args.Length > 2 Then
                Dim d = CDbl(args(2))
                Console.Write($", {d / 2}")
            End If
        End If
        Console.WriteLine()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Check(mySub As Action(Of Object()), ParamArray args As Object())
    mySub(args)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Check(AddressOf TestMsg, "With a string")
    Check(AddressOf TestMsg, "With a string and int", 1)
    Check(AddressOf TestMsg, "With a string, int, and double", 5, 123.45)
End Sub
```

> With a string
>
> With a string and int, 6
>
> With a string, int, and double, 10, 61.725

Comment: Thanks Djv. It worked perfectly. However, when I tried with more than one argument as this: Sub Check(Of T)(mySub As Action(Of T), arg1 As T, arg2 As String, arg3 As String)
        mySub(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    End Sub  ----- I got error message that "too many arguments to action(of T)"

Comment: `Sub Check(Of T)(mySub As Action(Of T, String, String), arg1 As T, arg2 As String, arg3 As String)`

Comment: Thanks it works just as expected

Answer (score 0):

vb.net does have "CallByName" feature.

You can specify the sub you call by passing a string name.

So, say this code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

   Dim strSubToCall As String

    strSubToCall = "Sub1"
    CallByName(Me, strSubToCall, CallType.Method)

    strSubToCall = "Sub2"
    CallByName(Me, strSubToCall, CallType.Method, "String value passed")

    strSubToCall = "Sub3"
    CallByName(Me, strSubToCall, CallType.Method, "String value passed", 55)



End Sub

Sub Sub1()

    Debug.Print("Sub 1 called")

End Sub

Sub Sub2(s As String)

    Debug.Print("Sub 2 called - value passed = " & s)

End Sub

Sub Sub3(s As String, i As Integer)

    Debug.Print("Sub 3 called, values passed = " & s & " - " & i.ToString)

End Sub
```

output:

```
Sub 1 called
Sub 2 called - value passed = String value passed
Sub 3 called, values passed = String value passed - 55
```